# Should dependency inversion be used only with Adapters everywhere?

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control

As I understand the purpose of DI is that I can easily swap a lower level implementation. But it forces the lower level abstraction to be defined inside the higher level.

A lower level becomes dependent on the abstraction defined in the higher level and can't be used without it. But what if I would ever want to reuse my lower-level `Logger` class in another application?

Should I use Adapter everywhere with DI? In my example Adapter could implement `ILogger` interface from the higher-level code and reroute calls to the `Logger` class which now becomes reusable and independent from my application.

Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time passed and now I think that I can answer myself.

1. There is no sense to make an adapter when two interacting classes are located in the same dll. For such case it makes the code more complicated and difficult for refactoring but does not provide any benefits. If you want to reuse some functionality you still need to reference the whole dll so don't bother.
2. Each component (regardless of whether it's lower- or higher-level) should depend on abstractions (with only methods that it needs) which can be declared beside or in the same dll (if they are shared between multiple components).
3. There should be a special "setup" system which provides adapters and factories. Because no class knows about its dependencies implementation we need this system to construct objects and connect all solution parts together.

Comment: If you're looking for terms to google, your 'setup system' is usually called the _composition root_.

Answer (score 4):

You are very confused.

> A lower level becomes dependent on the abstraction defined in the higher level

No it doesn't. It depends only on the abstraction that it has defined **itself**. For instance, a `TaxAuditImpl` might depend on the interface `TaxAuditor` that it satisfies. However, it does *not* depend on the `SuperDuperPersonalFinanceManager` that *uses* the `TaxAuditor`. Everything stays nicely within its own level.

Admittedly, the `FinanceManager` *does* depend on the lower-level `TaxAuditor`, but that's okay - it can't very well use it without depending on it. And dependency injection serves to *reduce* this kind of dependency, because the `FinanceManager` doesn't have to know the `Impl`, just the interface.

Comment: The question is if you have two projects, does `TaxAuditor` live in the same project as `TaxAuditImpl` or `SuperDuperPersonalFinanceManager`?

Comment: Look at the diagram (figure 2) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Dependency_inversion.png , Package 2 (lower level) becomes dependent on the Package 1 (higher level). I propose to introduce an Adapter so that Package 2 can be used without Package 1.

Comment: I love answers like this.  When an answer begins with the statement "You are very confused" you can immediately tell that they guy who is answering it is after *the truth*, not the upvotes. (y)  Vlad, if you think that your question is indicative of anything but confusion on your part, you will have to amend it _extensively_ to show, with very clear and comprehensive examples, what on earth you are talking about.

Comment: -1. I have to disagree with this. The higher-level code (for example, the business logic) defines the interfaces it needs (for data-access, for example). Lower level code implements the interfaces which the high-level code exposes. If the high-level code depended on the interface defined by the low-level code, it would be impossible to plug in different implementations of the low-level code. (Explicitly referencing NHibernate's `ISession` abstraction in your business logic means you can't swap to Dapper if you need to.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, it's not very clear with what (or who) exactly you disagree. In your comment you described why do we need DI but what I said before is not contrary to that.  My question is about that when we use DI a low-level code becomes attached to (or dependent on) its "client" - higher-level code - and how to avoid this so such low-level code can be reused.

Comment: @Vlad Apologies, I wasn't clear. I'm disagreeing with Kilian Forth's answer; I believe that he is advising against the core proposition of  the dependency inversion principle. I think your question is a good one :)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: who defines the interface definition first is not always the same - it is neither "always" the higer level component nor always the "lower level component". See my answer, hopefully bringing some light into this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

> But it forces the lower level abstraction to be defined inside the higher level.

No, it does not enforce this. The "lower level abstraction" (the interface, like `ILogger` in your example) can be defined outside the "lower level" and the "higher level" component, it can reside in a third, independ DLL which serves only for the purpose of providing the interfaces. This component is neither part of the lower nor the higher level component.

Actually, I wrote "it can", because that is not the only possible design alternative. The other two alternatives (the one you suggested: ILogger in the higher level component, and the one suggested by @KilianFoth, ILogger as part of the Logger component), are also valid approaches, with the benefit that you need less DLLs/components, but also some drawbacks regarding to the resulting dependencies or restrictions on reusability. Putting the `ILogger` interface into the `Logger` DLL imposes that your "higher level component" still has to depend on the lower level Logger component, of course, but it still leaves you the option to replace the `Logger` object in your higher level component by a "test logger" for unit testing purposes, as long as you don't mind your test code having a linkage dependency  to the Logger DLL.

> A lower level becomes dependent on the abstraction defined in the higher level and can't be used without it.

No, it becomes dependent on the interface component. You cannot use the logger without that interface component, of course. But you can reuse the logger DLL in conjuction with the ILogger DLL in a completely separate project.

> In my example Adapter could implement ILogger interface from the higher-level code and reroute calls to the Logger class which now becomes reusable and independent from my application.

The typical usage scenario of an adapter is when you have incompatible interfaces and cannot easily modify the existing code. For example, where your higher level component `BusinessCalculator` expects a injected `BLogger` (an interface, maybe defined in the DLL where `BusinessCalculator` lives, with some special requirements). Your standard `Logger` component which you have already used in five other projects and for which you are not going to change the design, resides in your "Reusable Logger" DLL and provides only an incompatible `ILogger` interface (maybe directly defined in your Logger DLL, maybe defined in a separate interface DLL). Then you need an adapter class which maps the `BLogger` calls to `ILogger`.

By the latter design, you can indeed decouple the `BusinessCalculator` and `Logger` components completely, only the adapter will depend on the DLLs where `BLogger` and `ILogger` are defined. Technically, it is not even clear any more which of the two is the more "higher level" or "lower level" component. The drawback is the additional overhead for managing all those different interfaces and components.